# How to automatically insert parenthesis after Intellisense autocompletes method names in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

Is there any way to do it?
Any option or free extension is welcome as an answer

Solution must be applicable in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: When opening a parenthesis in visual studio 2017, a corresponding closing parenthesis is created automatically, and you can type in between them.

Comment: @machine_1 point is to do it without opening parenthesis, just by pressing tab

Comment: @aggelosgaraleas, now we do not have this feature, others shared this suggestion to the VS Product Team in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010195/how-to-automatically-insert-parenthesis-after-intellisense-autocompletes-method, we can vote it, thank you for your sharing.

Answer (score 3):

You can type `(` to finish autocompletion and spawn closing parentheses.

Comment: I like the solution but i find it more of a bypass. I was trying to find a way to do it by hitting tab, as i always do to finish autocompletion.